# update or upgrade ubuntu pc from another computer on the local workgroup network

Tags: server, upgrade, services, sharing, update-alternatives

How to share updates between ubuntu computers on the local workgroup network

Any option like windows 10 os?

Comment: Ubuntu updates tend to be smaller and more frequent than Windows updates. Years ago, the [debtorrent](https://wiki.debian.org/DebTorrent) project tried this, However, folks found that updates tended to be too small (and the entire package database too large) and changed too frequently for this method of updates to be preferable to the existing server-based methods. Creating your own local mirror using a proxy is fairly easy, and that is the common method for in-house sharing today.

Comment: An HTTP caching proxy like [Sqid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) will cache Ubuntu updates locally in your network. So once updates are requested and downloaded by one computer, they will remain available for other computers locally.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-cache search apt-proxy` to get a list of proxies being _apt_.